# Episode of "Full Metal Panic!" where Captain Testarossa rebukes a disloyal mercenary

Tags: episode-identification, full-metal-panic

I have watched all the seasons of the anime *Full Metal Panic!*, except the last season "Invisible Victory", of which I only watched the first few episodes.

In one of the episodes, the Captain, Teletha Testarossa, speaks with one of the mercenaries working for her, a blonde man, accompanied by a few other men. He starts by complaining that he never signed up just to die, because they were about to embark on a very dangerous mission, where getting killed on duty was very likely. He goes on by saying he is only a mercenary, working only for money, never caring about loyalty and such things. Cpt. Testarossa then goes into a very dramatic and inspiring speech, rebuking him directly, making the mercenary come to tears even. She ends her speech with the words: "Survive, that is an order!", making him salute her with tears and solid determination in his eyes.

Which episode of *Full Metal Panic!* was that scene shown in?

Comment: This tumblr picture (with that quote) is tagged FMPIV02; https://sumbudum.tumblr.com/post/173183442288/survive-that-is-an-order-so-tessa-was-pretty. Invisible Victory: Episode 2? https://myanimelist.net/anime/31931/Full_Metal_Panic_Invisible_Victory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from "Invisible Victory" episode 2, timestamp 19'58, as shown in this reaction video:

The scene starts at 17'09 in the episode, so about 27'11 in the reaction video.